# Operations in a matrix with its (i,j) values with no for or while loops

Tags: r, matrix

I need to write a function in R that receives as inputs the number of rows (r) and the number of columns (c) and generates and output matrix V, where V_(i,j) = r^(abs(i-j)) and r = 2. This function must not have `for` nor `while` loops.

I just don't know how to access every (i,j) and compute de difference without the use of for and while loops.

So far I have tried with the following code.

```
matriz <- function(r,c){
  r <- 2
  V <- matrix(r^(abs(nrow(r)-ncol(c))), nrow =  r, ncol = c)
  return(V)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are replacing every value of `r` with 2 every time you run this function

Comment: @nsinghs I know. That is why I'm asking, that is the code I've been trying to run.

Comment: Is `r` always going to be 2?

Comment: @nsinghs yes, the value of r is constant and equal to 2. The only variation is the exponent, where for each V_(i,j) the value should be r^(abs(i-j))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
foo <- function(r,c){
    m <- matrix(NA,r,c)
    2 ^ abs(row(m) - col(m))
}
```

...with obvious extensions for different bases:

```
foo <- function(i,r,c){
    m <- matrix(NA,r,c)
    i ^ abs(row(m) - col(m))
}
```

Comment: Nice :) Good answer.